Invertible neural network 1 input/output but higher dimensionnal hidden layers
I want to create an Invertible Neural Network that has 1 input, it expands into hidden layers with multiple neurons and ends with 1 output.
The constraints are, my neural network will have strictly positive weights, and ends with a sigmoid activation function. By ensuring positive weights and bijective activation functions my output will be bijective too even with higher dimensionnal hidden layers.
ChatGPT gave me a solution that is to augment the data with extra dimensions (e.g., noise variables that are later marginalized out) but it seems over complicated and inefficient.
Does anyone know an alternative to have those hidden layers with multiple neurons that allows to create any complex hidden pattern. Not just affine functions.
